# How to use RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle in SwiftUI for TextField after API change in Xcode 11 Beta 5?

Tags: xcode, textfield, swiftui, beta

Before Xcode 11 Beta 5. I used this syntax to put a rounded border outside my TextField:

```
TextField("Expression", text: $expression)
      .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
```

Sadly, this approach is deprecated and gives me warning now.

The new approach should be: roundedBorder' is deprecated: Use `RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle` directly instead.

But I can't figure out a way to use it.

As I can tell from the developer documentation. RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle conforms to protocol TextFieldStyle.

And TextField seems to have RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle as nested struct?(Not sure if I understanding correctly, RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle is written below TextField in the developer documentation)

I can't figure out how to use the new RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle.

I'm looking for the correct way to write the code below in Beta 5:

```
    TextField("Placeholder", text: $texts)
        .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You say:

```
 .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
```

Comment: OMG thanks! I thought the textFieldStyle(_:) has been deprecated as well. It was crossed out on the documentation .  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/textfield/3277174-textfieldstyle?changes=latest_beta

Answer (score 0):

```
 .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle.init())
```

You can use both

```
 .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
```